# How to use regular expression in spark dataframe using scala?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

In my case i have a data frame contaning some biological data which are: protein name, ecnumber (which could be more than one) and protein domains (which could be also more than one domain). The data frame is a one column containing all those data which i would like to split it into three columns, but the problem is that if a line (containing more than one ECnumber) is splitted, the second ECnumber goes to the third column and the domains will be then disappeared.

here is my code:

```
val df = rdd.toDF()
val mydf = df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"value", ";")).select(
  $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("Entry"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("ECnumber"),
  $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("Domains")
```

And here is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs17z.png)

Comment: So what is the question here? can you add some input data and expected result and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: The question is how can i split the df column into 3 columns where the protein name takes index [0] , the ecnumber (which it could be more than one) takes index [1] and the domains take the index [2] ?
Oh the result is in the image

Comment: can you add some sample input data ?

Comment: ...or explain how do you decide where ecnumbers stop and domains start if they all split by a `;`?

Comment: some proteins have just one ec number so you find it in the csv file written as follows:

P78LO5; 1.2.5.3 ; "IPRO7245 .....;"
If a protein contains many ecnumber you find it as:

P78LO5; "1.2.5.3 , 1.9.7.12" ; "IPRO7245 .....;"

The ecnumber should start with " and ends with " if they are multiple and same for the domains

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided reference data, I see you can use the following regular expression to retrieve your data into independent columns (by extracting using regular expression):

```
val dataFrameValueRegex = "(\\w++);(([0-9.-]*+;)++)((\\w++;?)++)".r
```

For example if data frame value has got the following:

```
val dataFrameValue = "A6MML6;2.1.-.-;2.1.3.16;IPR037431;IPR037432;IPR037433"
```

*Now using regular expression, you can extract independent values from data frame value*:

```
val dataFrameValueRegex(entry, ecNumbers, _, domains, _) = dataFrameValue
```

Above: All values will be retrieved in corresponding variables:
1.) entry: Entry string
2.) ecNumbers: Complete string of ecnumbers separated by semicolon's. There would be a semicolon present at the end of the string.
3.) domains: Complete string of domains separated by semicolon's.

Note: If for any reason the data frame value was not as expected you would get a MatchError exception been thrown.

In the below code just printing variables information.

```
println(s"Data value: Entry = [$entry], ECnumbers = [${ecNumbers.init}], Domains = [$domains]")

val ecNumber = ecNumbers.init.split(";")
ecNumber.foreach(e => println(s"ecNumber = [$e]"))

val domain = domains.split(";")
domain.foreach(d => println(s"Domain = [$d]"))
```